# Javascript/Jquery won't load from a file in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Why javascript/jquery does not load when I import from an external file? I tried many different ways As I can. It is just so annoying.

---

First try:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

But no luck

---

I put the js file into a subfolder as second Try:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../foldername/script.js"></script>
```

Nothing

---

I even imported a jquery library as for the third attempt:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="../script.js"></script>
```

It does nothing....

---

I even put double `../../` after `src=""`, like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../script.js"></script>
```

Still nothing.

---

What did I do wrong? I used to work with javascript/Jquery before and it worked, but now... 
*This question may helpful for others.*

I copied the code from this site: https://codepen.io/MarcRay/pen/vmJBn

Comment: How do you know it does nothing? What does the console say?

Comment: @peeebeee I tried in jsfiddle and it is working there with no problem.

Comment: Have you checked script.js in google chrome's source or you getting error of not loading in console?

Comment: The console says: "`TypeError: $(...).a is not a function`"
Hmmm.

Comment: @Dhiren I have never got that error before.

Comment: @Galarist I think then your script.js is loading fine but their might be some error in javascript file coding.

Comment: @Dhiren I edited my question. I copied the code from that website.

Comment: @Dhiren Ok I found the issue

Comment: @Galarist what was the issue?

Comment: @Dhiren I copied the jQuery code from codepen. To make it work at my side, I had to make the code to be tidy on codepen then I copied all the code again.

Comment: oh, so is it now working or not?

Comment: Yes it worked/working.